# Массовая замена в файлах

Tags: файлы, файловая-система, замена

Есть статичная версия интернет-магазина, не спрашивайте откуда. 
Заказчику нужно заменить все цены. Исходные и конечные цены у меня выписаны в файлах. Нужна программа/скрипт, в который можно импортировать файл, где исходные данные и в другой столбец конечные данные, и чтобы он их заменил, собственно. **Всякие notepad, dream не подходят**, т.к. там только по одному заменять нужно, а у меня в одном файле по 50 цен менять придется. Есть у кого что на примете?

Comment: а как вы будете отличать цену от других цифровых данных - артикулов, дат и тп ?

Comment: Все схвачено, все цены в точности выписаны в файл, других таких цифр нет

Answer (score 0):

Очень рекомендую использовать библиотеку Pandas, она, собственно, под это и заточена.